# 'std::bad_alloc' or even wrong vector size when using iterator on vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I got `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` when trying to push an additional string to a middle of a vector. I used g++ 4.8.2.

I even got output with wrong vector sizes `size of str_vector 0: 1, size of str_vector 1: 1` when using g++ 5.2 on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

The program works correctly when I use index (e.g., `str_vector[0]`) to access vectors or use `std::list`.

Does this mean there is some restriction on the use of `iterator`? I assume that there should not any difference when I use index or iterator to access vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main() {
        vector<vector<string>> str_vector;

        str_vector.emplace_back();
        vector<vector<string>>::iterator it0 = std::prev(str_vector.end());
        it0->push_back("a");

        str_vector.emplace_back();
        vector<vector<string>>::iterator it1 = std::prev(str_vector.end());
        it1->push_back("a");

        it0->push_back("a"); // bad alloc here

        std::cerr << "size of str_vector 0: " << it0->size() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "size of str_vector 1: " << it1->size() << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty much every implementation of the standard library has a compiler option that provides diagnostics. Enable those and try again. The `bad_alloc` is just a symptom caused by undefined behaviour of your code.

Comment: What is that iterator needed for anyway? I've never seen someone use an iterator for `push_back`.

Comment: I wanted to have references to each inner vector in the vector. Thereby, I can add strings to each inner vector on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are nothing but *object oriented* pointers. Iterator invalidation is a lot like pointer invalidation.

C++ Spec:

> vector: all iterators and references before the point of insertion are
>   unaffected, unless the new container size is greater than the previous
>   capacity (in which case all iterators and references are invalidated)
>   [23.2.4.3/1]

First time you execute the below line, it's valid.Second time you do it with the same iterator, the iterator has already been invalidated:

```
    it0->push_back("a"); // bad alloc here
```

For knowing what iterator invalidation is and how to handle it , there is this excellent post on iterator invalidation here:

[[Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules][1])

Comment: The answer explains everything :)

Comment: check visitor design pattern and how it is applicable to stl containers..that is the essence of iterators.

Answer (score 3):

When you add elements to a vector it might need to reallocate its internal memory, which leads to all iterator to become invalid. So after you do the second `emplace_back` the first iterator `it0` becomes invalid.

Comment: Is using vector indexes, which are not invalidated after pushes, the only viable option to get a reference to each inner vector? I wanted to add strings to each inner vector on the fly.